# Enabling multiple CORS for Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a Web API I wrote and one application utilizing it. SO I added CORS header for that applicaiton by adding a header to the controller class within my API:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:59452", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

The above worked fine. Now I also want more applications consuming that web API. My question is how do I make this happen?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add multiple origins by separating them with commas:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:59452,http://localhost:25495,http://localhost:8080", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: Is this the current method? I see other questions/answer where the users had to create lots of code to achieve it.

Comment: @Sean Bright can I use origins:"*" to allow any domain?

Comment: Chrome and others block this, throwing an error about multiple values and only one is allowed.

Answer (score 28):

Sean's answer is good enough for simple scenarios but please note that an attribute argument must be a constant expression, so you can't say `[EnableCors(origins:GetAllowedOrigins()...` If a client changes their origin or you need to add a new one you will need to make code changes and re-deploy site to the server.

As an alternative you can enable CORS in the `WebApiConfig.cs` `Register()` method.This enables CORS globally but allows you to dynamically set the allowed origins.This allows you to maintain a list of allowed origins in a database for example and can be updated as needed.You would still need to restart the web application after any changes but no code changes will be necessary:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    private static string GetAllowedOrigins()
    {
        //Make a call to the database to get allowed origins and convert to a comma separated string
        return "http://www.example.com,http://localhost:59452,http://localhost:25495";
    }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        string origins = GetAllowedOrigins();
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to dynamically use the AllowedOrigins list for a specific action not globally enabled???

Comment: @Moes you can create a custom attribute that implements ICorsPolicyProvider and source the origins from config, database, etc. - any source you want.

Comment: Does this get around the issue of Chrome throwing a fit over multiple origins in the list when only one is allowed?

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko No.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it depends on the requester.  According to [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad#how-it-works), only one origin is allowed.  The comma delimited string approach suggested above appears to work in [test-cors](http://www.test-cors.org/), but not in [an SPFx web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Also the wildcard (*) origin does not work in cases where cookie/credentials are included (at least in SPFx).
[image]